# POST sanitizing and avoiding nested if blocks

Tags: php

When sanitizing the $_POST passed from the controller to the model, I need to sanitize the input and there are 2 options that I can think of.

For the first one, I can nest the `if` blocks like this:

```
if(!empty($username))
{
            if(!empty($password))
            {
              //login the user
            }
            else 
            {
                echo 'Please enter password.'
            }
 }
 else 
 {
    echo 'Please enter username.'
 }
```

And the other one is like this:

```
   if(empty($username))
    {
        $err[] = 'Please enter username';                
    }
    if(empty($password))
    {
        $err[] = 'Please enter password.';                
    }
    if(empty($err)){
        //login the user
    }
    else
    {
        //display error
    }
```

Which way is the preferred one and is there another, smarter way of sanitizing the input?

Comment: These two options — at least the excerpts you have shown us — aren't equivalent.

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: On Code Review, we review real code, not concepts. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Ok, I edited my examples. How about now?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find if it is a short function, that you do your validation and exit early, these are usually called "guard" clauses

What you are doing here is more what I would call validation, than sanitizing. Eg. sanitizing would be escaping data before feeding it into and sql statement.

```
$err = [];

if(empty($username))
{
    $err[] = 'Please enter username';                
}

if(empty($password))
{
    $err[] = 'Please enter password.';                
}

if(count($err) > 0 ) {
    //display error
    return; 
}

//login the user
```

Comment: What is the difference between `if(count($err) > 0 ) {` and `if($err)`

Comment: Not much really, just because it is an array i use count, it is just out of habbit, what i was really trying to illustrate is splitting that last if/else block, to keep it similar to the if block's you have above it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I decided to go with approach.